# view two maildirs as one in mutt/neomutt

Tags: email, unix, mutt, maildir, notmuch

Simplifying another question about [merging multiple email accounts](https://superuser.com/q/1107704/576570):

I have two maildirs. How do I get a combined listing of both - either in Mutt or NeoMutt? This means where the messages are sorted together in a single view as if the two maildirs had been merged (but without actually merging them).

Apparently this can be done with [Notmuch](https://notmuchmail.org/); I'm looking for a minimal example so I can get my feet wet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution here is the same as [merge multiple email accounts in single view in mutt](https://superuser.com/questions/1107704/merge-multiple-email-accounts-in-single-view-in-mutt)

One important thing. The both maildirs must be in under the same directory tree where notmuch database path is.

notmuch example:
`~/.notmuch-config`

```
…
[database]
path=/home/yourusername/.mail
…
```

maildirs:

```
~/.mail/mailbox1/{cur,new,tmp}
~/.mail/mailbox2/{cur,new,tmp}
# or even following works
~/.mail/mailbox1/{cur,new,tmp}
~/.mail/mailbox1/mailbox2/{cur,new,tmp}
```

Then run `notmuch new` to index messages in the database.

neomutt config:

```
set nm_default_uri  = "notmuch:///home/yourusername/.mail"

named-mailboxes \
    "Archive"      "notmuch://?query=*&type=threads" \
    "unread"       "notmuch://?query=tag:unread" \
```

Comment: You gave a config file and the locations of some maildirs, but I need more detail than this. For example, what command needs to be run to view the maildirs in a single view? Maybe it would help if you pretend that you are writing a Bash script that takes the location of two maildirs as arguments, and then opens them together in Neomutt. This could involve symlinking them into a temporary directory, creating a notmuch config in that directory, and so on. If you write a script that can be run in this way, then you can be sure that your readers have enough detail. Thanks.

Comment: I added command to execute and neomutt config example. Then it's up to you, what mailboxes and queries you want.